# Did Thanos' plan include the planets he visited before?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Before Thanos acquires all the Infinity Stones in *Avengers: Infinity War*, he had already been going around to many planets, killing off half the population:

- Drax's planet
- Gamora's planet
- The planets of several prisoners seen in GotG
- The (20+ years) of additional populations of the planets

He's already killed hundreds of thousands in that time... did those planets' populations get halved again after the snap? So Gamora's planet is 25% of what it was before Thanos ever shows up?

Comment: I'm sure this (or a variation) must have been asked here somewhere before...

Comment: Why wouldn't it? There wasn't any indication of a caveat in the movie.

Comment: Seems like it was asked on Quora, after finally getting the "right search terms" for google to spit out a meaningful answer

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [Does Thanos intend to exert his plan on each planet individually or the entire universe as a whole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88821/49) as well as [Did Thanos's calculations account for aftermath effects?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88741/49).

Answer (score 5):

## We don't know

His plan is to snap his fingers, kill half of all life in the universe and then sit back and bask in the glow of the gratitude of the remaining population.

This is **ALL LIFE** including plants, animals etc. as was recently confirmed by the creators.

> In an interview with Birth Movies Death, Marvel Studios CEO Kevin Feige confirmed that it wasn't just people that died with that finger snapping. When asked about plants and animals, Feige confirmed that half of the plants and animals of the world are now gone, too. He said, "Yes! Yes. All life."
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://screenrant.com/infinity-war-thanos-snap-animals-plants-killed/)</sup>

**There is no indication of *specificity* in the movie or *targeting* planet by planet in the snap. What we *see* is it's effects on the heroes we know, probably for scale reasons.**

Given the sheer amount of life (not just **people**) in the universe going planet by planet in the snap would probably *not* be ideal but then we don't know how the Infinity Stones actually work.

Certainly, before he obtained the Stones he was proceeding on a planet by planet basis because *that's the only method available to him* which is, I feel, the source of the confusion.

Comment: I find it kinda odd that plants and animals should have been decimated as well, as these pose as a part of the resources available to the people on the planets. Also we don't see any plant (except Groot) vanishing (and I doubt that Groot is a plant as we know it)

Comment: Unforeseen side effect - an example of be careful what you wish for? Mind you - the large amount of of domesticated animals and plants to support human life are as much a distortion to ecosystems as humans are...